# How to take a backup of a big filestream enabled db without the files

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a large >40Gb filestream enabled db in Production. I would like to automatically make a backup of this db and restore it to staging, for testing deployments. The nature of our environment is such that the filestream data is > 90% of the data and I don't need it in staging.

Is there a way that I can make a backup of the db without the filestream data, as this would drastically reduce my staging disk and network requirements, while still enabling me to test a (somewhat) representative sample of prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a fairly recent version of SQL Server.  Since this is production, I am assuming you are in full recovery model.

You can’t just exclude individual tables from a backup.  Backup and restore do not work like that.  The only possibility i can think is to do a backup of just the file groups that do not contain the filestream.  I am not 100% sure if you will be able to restore it though since I have never tried it.  Spend some time researching partial backups and restoring a file group and give it a try.

Comment: yeah i was kinda hoping someone would know this would work, probably worth investigating

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Generate Scripts` and interface and do one of the following:

- copy all SQL objects and the data (without the `filestream` tables) and recreate the database
- copy all SQL objects without the data; create the objects in new database on the current SQL instance; copy the data that you need directly from the first database;

The first is lazy and probably will not work well with big database. The second will work for sure, but you need to sync the data by your own.

In both cases, open this interface:

[image]

Then choose all objects and all tables without the big ones:

[image]

From this option you can control the data extraction (skip or include):

[image]

---

I guess it will be best to script all the objects without the data. Then create a `model` database. You can even add some sample data in your `model` database. When you are changing the the production database (create new object, delete object, etc), apply these changes on your `model` database, too. Having such `model` database means you are having a copy of your production database with all supported functionalities and you can restore a this `model` database on every test SQL instance you want.

Comment: i know i didn't add it to the question, but I'd like to automate the process, this excludes this method of doing things, but this will be handy for the first time copy